# Starting with accelerometers, which to choose?

Tags: accelerometer, arduino, pic

So I am trying to buy a low cost accelerometer to use with my Arduino and PIC projects. I don't know much about them, and would appreciate some advice.

I have come across two which interest me: the ADXL345, and the MMA7361. Those seem to be the cheapest around with a good record. If there are any others, please let me know what you recommend - or help me choose between these two.

With that said, I was looking at the ADXL345 on eBay, and found something weird.
http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Arduino-Triple-Axis-Accelerometer-Breakout-ADXL345-/130492972527?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e61fcbdef

http://www.ebay.ca/itm/ADXL345-3-axis-Digital-Sensor-Acceleration-Module-Arduino-/270904019741?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f13234b1d

The one in the first link is cheaper, but also smaller. It seem like the same thing as the second, but I am wondering why it is smaller and looks like it has less components. I do know it is missing the pins, which I can solder on myself if I purchase it. But anyways, why do they physically seem so different?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Maybe better fit in http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the 2nd link includes the pull-up resistors for the I2C interface. Hard to tell on the 1st link though.